# C++ Overloading [] from left and right

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-overloading

I'm trying to think how can I overload [] from both left and right to function as set and get for a custom string class I'm working on. for example:

```
char x= objAr[1]; //get
objAr[2]='a'; //set
```

The string class basically looks like this:

```
class String {
private:
    char* data;
    unsigned int dataSize;
public:
    String();
    String(char);
    String(char*);
    String(String&);
    ~String();
    char* getData();
    int getSize();
};
```

Comment: Note that C++ isn't Python where `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are different functions. C++ only has one single `operator[]` that does both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you always have the data to back it up, you can return a reference:

```
char& String::operator[] (size_t idx)
{ return data[idx]; }

char String::operator[] (size_t idx) const
{ return data[idx]; }
```

In your case, that should be sufficient. However, if this was not option for whatever reason (e.g. if the data is not always of the proper type), you could also return a proxy object:

```
class String
{
  void setChar(size_t idx, char c);
  char getChar(size_t idx);

  class CharProxy
  {
    size_t idx;
    String *str;
  public:
    operator char() const { return str->getChar(idx); }
    void operator= (char c) { str->setChar(idx, c); }
  };

public:
  CharProxy operator[] (size_t idx)
  { return CharProxy{idx, this}; }

  const CharProxy operator[] (size_t idx) const
  { return CharProxy{idx, this}; }
};
```

This would also enable you to do things like implicit data sharing with copy-on-write.

Comment: `return CharProxy{idx, this};` may not be available since OP specified `c++`, not `c++11`.

Comment: @BetaCarotin Do we really need to still make allowances for no C++11? It's been out for 4 years.

Comment: If C++11 is not available, `CharProxy` needs a constructor, which should then be called in the `return` statements instead of the aggregate initialisation I used.

Comment: ... which makes it a better answer because it will motivate the OP to migrate to modern C++. (grin)